# Is there any way to activate right click on scroll bar of browser using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

***how to use right click on scroll bar scroller***

generally when we left click on scroll bar path then we move to position where mouse clicked but when  we right click on scroll bar it do nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simulate the events of clicking the right mouse button using the event `contextmenu`.

Next, we disable the default behavior of event `contextmenu` - we **disable** the appearance of the context menu:

```
event.preventDefault();
```

And with the help of calculations within the `if { ... }` condition, we get the result we need.  Target the scrollbar area, both by **X** and by **Y**:

```
event.offsetX > event.target.clientWidth || event.offsetY > event.target.clientHeight
```

Accordingly, instead of `console.log("Right click on the scrollbar!");`, you can use any logic that needs to be called.

```js
window.addEventListener("contextmenu", function (event) {
    if (event.offsetX > event.target.clientWidth || event.offsetY > event.target.clientHeight) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("Right click on the scrollbar!");
    }
});
```

```css
body {
    height: 5000px;
}
```

Comment: Great answer, but I would move `event.preventDefault();` inside the condition, in order to keep the default behavior in case the right-click is not done on the scroll bar.

Comment: @MihaiMatei. Thanks. Yes. I agree with you. It will be more correct according to your advice. Moved `event.preventDefault()` inside the condition.